# WriteFile returning error code 87

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I am working on a program that is writing to an HID device and am getting the error 87, Invalid parameter on the WriteFile function. I got the functions from Jan Axelson's USB Complete so I'm not sure why I am getting the error. 
I am using this to find my device:

```
private void USBInit()
    {
        IntPtr deviceInfoSet;
        Int32 memberIndex = 0;
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA MyDeviceInterfaceData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
        Int32 bufferSize = 0;
        IntPtr detailDataBuffer;
        Boolean success = false;
        deviceFound = false;

        HidD_GetHidGuid(ref hidGuid);           // Get the GUID

        deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs     // Get pointer to a device info set
            (ref hidGuid,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

        do
        {
            MyDeviceInterfaceData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(MyDeviceInterfaceData);   // Identify Device Interface
            success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces
                (deviceInfoSet,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                ref hidGuid,
                memberIndex,
                ref MyDeviceInterfaceData);

            success = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail           // Request Structure with Device Path Name
                (deviceInfoSet,
                ref MyDeviceInterfaceData,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0,
                ref bufferSize,
                IntPtr.Zero);

            detailDataBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
            Marshal.WriteInt32(detailDataBuffer, (IntPtr.Size == 4) ? (4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize) : 8);

            success = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail
                (deviceInfoSet,
                ref MyDeviceInterfaceData,
                detailDataBuffer,
                bufferSize,
                ref bufferSize,
                IntPtr.Zero);

            IntPtr pDevicePathName = new IntPtr(detailDataBuffer.ToInt32() + 4);
            devicePathName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pDevicePathName);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(detailDataBuffer);

            /* Request Communications Handle */
            deviceHandle = CreateFile
                (devicePathName,
                (GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ),
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                0);

            /* Get Vendor ID and Product ID */
            DeviceAttributes.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(DeviceAttributes);
            success = HidD_GetAttributes(deviceHandle, ref DeviceAttributes);

            // Compare Vendor ID and Product ID.
            if ((DeviceAttributes.VendorID == myVendorID) && (DeviceAttributes.ProductID == myProductID))
            {
                MessageBoxResult res = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Device Found", "K-IX", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                deviceFound = true;

                /* Get pointer to capabilities */
                success = HidD_GetPreparsedData(deviceHandle, ref preparsedData);

                /* Get Device Capabilities */
                Int32 result = 0;
                result = HidP_GetCaps(preparsedData, ref Capabilities);

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not my device
                memberIndex++;
                deviceHandle.Close();
                if (memberIndex == 128)
                { break; }
            }
        } while (!deviceFound);
    }
```

And this is the code I am using to try to send to the device:

```
private void SendUSB()
    {
        Int32 numberOfBytesWritten = 0;
        Byte[] outputReportBuffer = null;
        Boolean success;
        Boolean success2;
        // Set size of the Output report buffer.
        Array.Resize(ref outputReportBuffer, Capabilities.InputReportByteLength);

        // Store Report ID in first byte of header.
        outputReportBuffer[0] = 0;

        // Store report data following the Report ID.
        outputReportBuffer[1] = 0x01;
        //outputReportBuffer[2] = 0x02;
       // outputReportBuffer[3] = 0x03;
        // Send Report
        success = WriteFile
            (deviceHandle,
            outputReportBuffer,
            outputReportBuffer.Length,
            ref numberOfBytesWritten,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!success)
        {
            Int32 lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        success2 = HidD_FreePreparsedData(preparsedData);
    }
```

I have verified that my report length expected for the device is 2, but am not sure where to go from here as USB and HID programming are new for me.

Comment: I'm not an expert at dealing with HID devices, but Scott Hanselman's "[Is that you? Writing Better Software for Cool USB Hardware](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Is-that-you-Writing-Better-Software-for-Cool-USB-Hardware) might be a good reference, as it uses a lot less C++ idioms than your code above does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specified FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED in the CreateFile() call but pass a null for the lpOverlapped argument in the WriteFile() call.  That's not legal.

Remove the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED option.