# WriteFile Fails with error code 87 when writing to USB

Tags: windows, usb

I am trying to communicatate with a USB device on Windows 7. After I find the device using the vendor and product ID I open it with the following command

```
dev->device_handle = CreateFile( path, (GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ), 
                    (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE),
                    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL, 
                    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
```

Then I do a write into the device using

```
res = WriteFile(dev->device_handle, buf, length, &bytes_written, &ol);
```

where length is 64.

My device can read and write 64 bytes of data in this interface and this has been tested on Linux and using another tool in windows (I dont have the source of the tool).

The WriteFile function gives me an error code of 87. which is invalid parameters.

Could anybody please point me out the mistake I am making.

P.S. I have already analysed the question 
[WriteFile returning error code 87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184439/writefile-returning-error-code-87)

I have made some debug logs

```
--------------------------------------------------
Before write call
dev_handle:152
buf:2293463
length:65
bytes_written:0
overlap:0
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
After write call
dev_handle:152
buf:2293463
length:65
bytes_written:0
overlap:259
--------------------------------------------------
Last Error: 87
```

Comment: I think your "overlap" doesn't print right. It has quite a few members. Still, the information helps to exclude ` INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: Why do you think the overlap is 259?

Comment: Because you're printing it wrong. It isn't 259, because 259 is an integer value and `OVERLAPPED` is not an integer type.

Comment: I have a development. I initilaised the buf[0] = 0; I had accidently configured it to 0x01 for another device which communicates on report ID 0x01 and now I see the error has changed to 997 that is ERROR_IO_PENDING. I see a transmission on the hardware USB sniffer but the data is some garbage. So if I send like 10 times once the data is correct. Is there any way to clear or flush any buffer before this write

Comment: Well, if you send data using overlapped I/O, the immediate result will be I/O pending. That is the whole point of overlapped I/O ! Your confusion mat me caused by now waiting for the previous overlapped I/O to complete.

Comment: I am linux guy, and this is my first windows driver so, Why does an overlap error happen?

Comment: "Overlapped I/O" is Windows speak for Asynchronous I/O. The error is trying to get a result from an operation which is still pending. Same reason why `&bytes_written` doesn't make sense - the function generally returns while bytes are being written.

Comment: I have another board where I am supposed to communicate on the interface 1 i.e. the IN and OUT endpoints are moved to interface 1 along with the HID descriptor etc(earlier discussions were on interface 0). I identify the interface using the interface number (mi = 1), but here WriteFile operation gives error code 1784 i.e. ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are 5 parameters:

1. `dev->device_handle` could be `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` if `CreateFile` failed.
2. `buf` should not be `NULL`
3. `length` cannot be checked, so it can't be the problem.
4. `&bytes_written` is rather pointless (use `GetOverlappedResult`).
5. `&lo` must contain a valid offset and event. Also, all other fields must be zeroed.

Lacking context, we can't fault any specific parameter. I'd check `&bytes_written` first because it's the most obvious suspect to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made some debug logs and pasted it as an edit in the question. I have a condition to check the INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE